# force close when use SharedPreferences

Tags: android

sorry for my simple question, i'm beginner on android . when i use SharedPreferences, my app get crashed ! here is my code, please help me , Thank's alot .

```
    public class getToken extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            postTextandGetRespons("xxxxx/Service/register.php");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String responseStr) {
        String[] parts = responseString.split(":");
        success = parts[0];
        token = parts[1];
        if ( success.equals("success")) {
            SaveToken();
        }
    }
    public void SaveToken() {
        SharedPreferences token_save = getSharedPreferences("token_key", register.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editior2 = token_save.edit();
        editior2.putInt("token",Integer.valueOf(token));
        editior2.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is error? put your logcat

Answer (score 1):

it is `SharedPreferences` that is making your app crash but the fact that your `doInBackground` is returning null. The line which is making your app crash is

```
  String[] parts = responseString.split(":");
```

because `doInBackground` does

```
  return null;
}
```

if `postTextandGetRespons` returns a String you should do

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
    try {
        return postTextandGetRespons("xxxxx/Service/register.php");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

and in `onPostExecute` check agains `NPE`. E.g.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String responseStr) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(responseStr)) {
        Log.e("", " responseStr null");
        return;
    }
    String[] parts = responseString.split(":");
```

Comment: hi, i have problem yet :-(

Comment: what does it even mean ?

Comment: hey Blackbely looks, now i think doInBackground in my AsyncTask doesn't run !

Comment: what do you mean by *in my AsyncTask doesn't run*?